# Loading large dataset into Pandas Python

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I would like to load large .csv (3.4m rows, 206k users) open sourced dataset from InstaCart https://www.instacart.com/datasets/grocery-shopping-2017

Basically, I have trouble loading orders.csv into Pandas DataFrame. I would like to learn best practices for loading large files into Pandas/Python.

Answer (score 3):

Best option would be to **read the data in chunks instead of loading the whole file into memory**.

Luckily, `read_csv` method accepts `chunksize` argument.

```
for chunk in pd.read_csv(file.csv, chunksize=somesize):
    process(chunk)
```

Note: By specifying a `chunksize` to `read_csv` or `read_table`, the return value will be an `iterable` object of type `TextFileReader`:

Also see:

- [read_csv](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html)
- [Iterating through files chunk by chunk](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#io-chunking)

Comment: What if I need to load the entire dataset (~70GB) because I need to apply something like SVD or PCA?

Answer (score 0):

When you have large data frames that might not fit in memory, [dask](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/) is quite useful. The main page I've linked to has examples on how you can create a dask dataframe that has the same API as the pandas one but which can be distributed.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your machine you may be able to read all of it in memory by specifying the data types while reading the csv file. When a csv is read by pandas then the default data types used may not be the best ones. Using `dtype` you can specify the data types. It reduces the size of the data frame read into the memory.